# Problem calling webservice, possibly related to CORS

Tags: angular

I'm building angular app using VSCode, trying to call Web Service API built in ASP.NET core, I have tested web api using Postman and it works just fine.

When calling from angular app I get the following error

```
student-registration.component.ts:177 error
student-registration.component.ts:178 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at trainingcreditvalidation.service.ts:43
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
```

Here is my code for service piece

```
  getTraining()
  {
    console.log( 'gettraninig' );

    return fetch( 'http://localhost:51218/api/traininig/test', { mode: 'no-cors' } )
      .then( response => response.json() );
  }
```

and then the component making the call

```
    this.trainingCreditService.getTraining().then( ( response ) =>
    {
      response.json().then( ( data ) =>
      {
        console.log( 'TC Fetch: ' + JSON.stringify( data ) );
      } );
    } ).catch( ( err ) =>
    {
      console.log( err );
    } );
```

I made it based on the example in [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). If I take out `{ mode: 'no-cors' }` i get CORS Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
this.trainingCreditService.getTraining()
 .then( ( response ) => {
    console.log("TC Fetch", response)
    } )
 .catch( ( err ) => console.log( err ));
```

You have messed up some brackets, also the data coming from `getTraining()` is already in json format (you already converted it to json in your `getTraining()` method). So there is no need to call `json()` on it.

When calling API with fetch, you need to set your request mode to `'cors'`:

```
getTraining()
  {
    console.log( 'gettraninig' );

    return fetch( 'http://localhost:51218/api/traininig/test', { mode: 'cors' } )
      .then( response => response.json() );
  }
```

This is due to the Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS). By default the browsers don't allow any script running on one domain to access resource on another domain. So you need to add extra headers in your request to tell the browser to allow this request and setting the mode to `cors` does that for you.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) about CORS

Also have a look at different [modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) in fetch API

Comment: it only works when `{ mode: 'cors' }` but throws same error (Unexpected end of Input) when using `{ mode: 'no-cors' }` option

Comment: This is probably due to the server throughing error due to Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS)